# Three.js + OrbitControls - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, computer-vision, rendering, render

I am tryint to use `OrbitControls` in THREE.js. If I removed the line `let cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera)` from below, there will be no error. But now, I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

I tried to change `OrbitControls(camera)` to `THREE.OrbitControls(camera)`, and then I had "Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor".

I tried to import `OrbitControls.js` by using `<script src=...></script>` outside `"module"`, instead of `import {OrbitControls} from ...;`, but it doesn't work, I also tried to move `let cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera)` to other lines, but also doesn't work.

Any ideas how to fix?

```
<body>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';


let scene, renderer, camera
let cube

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene()
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)

  let cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera)

  camera.position.set(10, 10, 10)
  camera.lookAt(scene.position)

  // cube
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1))
  scene.add(cube)

}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

init()
render()

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> let cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera)

Always create the controls like so:

```js
let cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

The second parameter is mandatory now.